# sigaction handler does not close the process

Tags: c, asynchronous, signals

I have the following sigaction handler code

```
void signal_term_handler(int sig)
{
    int rc = async_lockf(pid_file, F_UNLCK);
    if(rc) {
        char piderr[] = "PID file unlock failed!\n";
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, piderr, (sizeof(piderr))-1);
    }
    close(pid_file);
    char exitmsg[] = "EXIT Daemon:TERM signal Received!\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, exitmsg, (sizeof(exitmsg))-1);
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //async-signal-save exit
}
```

All the function calls in the above function are an async-signal-save. Even the `async_lockf()` is an async-signal-save:

```
/*
 * The code of async_lockf is copied from eglibc-2.11.3/io/lockf.c
 * The lockf.c is under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * Copyright (C) 1994,1996,1997,1998,2000,2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 * This file is part of the GNU C Library.
*/

int async_lockf(int fd, int cmd)
{
    struct flock fl = {0};

    /* async_lockf is always relative to the current file position.  */
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_CUR;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_len = 0;

    switch (cmd)
    {
        case F_TEST:
            /* Test the async_lock: return 0 if FD is unlocked or locked by this process;
             return -1, set errno to EACCES, if another process holds the lock.  */
            fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;
            if (fcntl (fd, F_GETLK, &fl) < 0)
                return -1;
            if (fl.l_type == F_UNLCK || fl.l_pid == getpid ())
                return 0;
            errno = EACCES;
            return -1;

        case F_ULOCK:
            fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
            cmd = F_SETLK;
            break;
        case F_LOCK:
            fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
            cmd = F_SETLK;
            break;
        case F_TLOCK:
            fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
            cmd = F_SETLK;
            break;

        default:
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
    }

    /* async_lockf() is a cancellation point but so is fcntl() if F_SETLKW is
     used.  Therefore we don't have to care about cancellation here,
     the fcntl() function will take care of it.  */
    return fcntl (fd, cmd, &fl);
}
```

the sigaction handler should close the application if I execute `kill -15` command but some times I get the processus running and does not exit. this happens rarely. For example If I launch the application and then I stopped with `kill -15` 1000 times, this behaviour will happens only ~5 times

Any explaination for this strange behaviour? Why my application does not exist? Especially that I m using async-signal-save function (`_exit()`) to close the processus

Comment: For what it's worth, all of the operations in your signal handler except for writing the messages are useless. Files are automatically closed when a process terminates, and locks are automatically released when a file is closed.

Comment: who is responsible to close and to unlock the file? is it the atexit() function or it's the linux scheduler?

Comment: When a process dies, no matter how it dies, all of its open file descriptors are closed. Maybe you are confusing this with stdio `FILE`s, which need to be flushed as part of `exit` in userspace. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html and note that the "Consequences of Process Termination" apply even if `_exit` was not called explicitly, e.g. if the process terminated due to an unhandled signal.

Comment: @R.. In fact waiting the file to be closed and unlocked by the linux and not by the application, this could cause timing problems. I see this problem when I restart my application in foreground  3 times for example: `/etc/init.d/myapp &; /etc/init.d/myapp &; /etc/init.d/myapp &`

Comment: What? I don't follow. You can't even necessarily observe whether the file was closed just-before `_exit` or during `_exit`.

Comment: any way I need to execute the file unlock and the exit in my sigaction handler. but as you see there is a risk that coul be not executed

Answer (score 1):

To see what's happening, try attaching `strace` or `gdb` to the process and to see where it's stuck. My best guess is that you have code that's masking signals (`sigprocmask`) while performing a blocking operation, thus preventing the signal handler from running.

Comment: In fact my program is containing threads. I have thread which send signal sometimes with `pthread_cond_signal`. could this be the cause?

Comment: That shouldn't be related. Despite the similar name, signaling condition variables has nothing to do with signals.

Comment: so in my code I have not code that's masking signals (`sigprocmask`) while performing a blocking operation

Comment: so your guess is not the cause of my problem. this should another thing . is it true?

Comment: As I said, try using `strace` or `gdb` to find the cause.