# Why "kill -15" fails sometimes?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, kill

I have a program developed in C. This program contains 2 sub threads. Some times, When I try to stop my application with `kill -15 <pid of main thread>` the application does not exit. And I can see only the pid of the main thread in the `ps aux` output (The pids of the subthreads are not displayed in the outpout of the `ps aux`). And keep killing the remaining pid with `kill -15 <pid>` does not cause the termination of this process. Only `kill -9 <pid>` will cause the termination of the process.

This behaviour happens 3 times in 1000 tries.

- The OS is OpenWRT Linux
- The kernel version is 2.6.30
- Libs: `libuClibc-0.9.30.1.so` and `libpthread-0.9.30.1.so`

Please do not consider this topic duplicated with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025730/sigaction-handler-does-not-close-the-process), because my program does not contain sigaction handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not duplicate, but the answer is the same. Attach strace or gdb and see what it's doing when it's hung. However there are only two explanations: either you (or some library code you're using) blocked `SIGTERM` with `sigprocmask`, or the process is stuck in uninterruptable sleep in the kernel, which is usually a result of attempting to access a failing storage device like a dying hard drive or scratched optical disc.

Could you elaborate on what OS, kernel version, libraries, etc. you're using?

Comment: - The OS is OpenWRT Linux
 - The kernel version is 2.6.30
 - Libs: `libuClibc-0.9.30.1.so` and `libpthread-0.9.30.1.so`

Comment: Oh. Is uClibc configured for LinuxThreads rather than NPTL? If so, it does all kinds of broken stuff with signal handling and you really have no hope of having it work right.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So I have to find other solution. Could you provide some topics links that talking about this problem

Comment: There is the old [LinuxThreads FAQ](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~xleroy/linuxthreads/faq.html) but it really does not address these issues well. Perhaps there's a document from NPTL that better explains the flaws in the old LinuxThreads implementation.

Comment: Please excuse the following plug. :-) You could also potentially use [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org) instead of uClibc for building your program, to get a properly working threads implementation. This is easy if you static link your binary, but it's also possible to install a shared version alongside uClibc, and I believe recent versions of OpenWRT officially support building the whole system with musl instead of uClibc.